# How to update state value of array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have two APIs that return JSON data. In my state variable, I have an empty array. I want to append those JSON data in my empty array when I call useEffect.

This is my Context.

```
const AppContext = createContext()
const urls = ['api/load-all-news/0/20', 'api/load-all-news/20/20']


const initialState = {
    allNews: [],

    
}

const AppProvider=({children})=>{
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);


     
    const getAllNews = async(url)=>{
      try{
        const res = await fetch(url)
        const data = await res.json()
        
        dispatch({ type: "ALL_NEWS", payload: data.news_list})
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    
       useEffect(()=>{
          for(let i=0; i<urls.length;i++){
            getAllNews(urls[i])
          }
       },[])
  
    
    return<AppContext.Provider value={{...state}}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
}

const useGlobalContext=()=>{
    return useContext(AppContext)
}

export {AppContext, AppProvider, useGlobalContext}
```

This is my Reducer

```
const Reducer = (state, action) => {

  if (action.type === "ALL_NEWS") {
     
   const {allNews} =  state
  

    return {
      ...state,
     allNews: [...allNews, action.payload]
    };
  }
    return state;
}

export default Reducer;
```

My final allNews array should be [Array(20), Array(20)]. Arrays from two APIs. but Its showing [Array(20), Array(20), Array(20), Array(20)]. How do we solve this issue? please tell me what I am doing wrong. The values of indices 2, and 3 are the same as indexes 0,1 respectively.

Comment: How many times the useEffect gets triggered?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is caused by the dispatch call inside the loop in the `useEffect`. Instead of dispatching inside the loop, merge the data from both API calls and then dispatch it once. A sample would look like:

```js
...
const getAllNews = async (url) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();
      return data.news_list;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchNews = async () => {
      const allNews = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        const news = await getAllNews(urls[i]);
        allNews.push(news);
      }
      dispatch({ type: "ALL_NEWS", payload: allNews });
    };

    fetchNews();
  }, []);
// ...rest
```

and the reducer code:

```js
// Reducer code
const Reducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === "ALL_NEWS") {
    return {
      ...state,
      allNews: action.payload,
    };
  }
  return state;
};

export default Reducer;
```

Comment: its working but  when I console.log then the allNews value first it shows empty array and then rendering the same output twice in React 18. Why?

Comment: @ShabnamSabah are you using `<StrictMode>` in your `index.jsx`?

Comment: Please read the last `Caveat` [here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#setstate-caveats)  for React `18.x.x.`. "In Strict Mode, React will call your updater function twice in order to help you find accidental impurities."

Comment: yeah I am using Strict mode.

Comment: @ShabnamSabah Then that is the reason. It's not a problem since it is the react norms. It won;t happen in production mode. Please read the next comment that I posted.

Comment: @many8055 thanks .. but my two API's are loading very slowly .. how to solve this? Here is the api https://jugerkanthobd.com/api/load-all-news/0/20, https://jugerkanthobd.com/api/load-all-news/20/20

Comment: @ShabnamSabah sure will take a look in some time. There are some work so it'll take time for me but I can guide you if you want.